# Full path name of the current file using the ReSharper open API

Tags: visual-studio-2008, resharper, resharper-5.0

I am new to [ReSharper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReSharper) and was trying to write some simple plugins. I wanted to try to get full path of the file I am currently using.

Something like "C:\Project1\Firstfile.cs". If I am using "FirstFile.cs" in Visual Studio.

I was planning to show the full path as tooltip. Information of the few APIs I need to use to get the path would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
public ICSharpFile CSFile = _process.ProjectFile.GetPsiFile(CSharpLanguageService.CSHARP) as ICSharpFile;
public IProjectFile ProjFile = CSFile.GetProjectFile();
```

Now, *ProjFile.Location.ToString()* should return you the complete path of your projectFile.

Good Luck!!
Shaun

Comment: What is "_process" and where to get it?

Answer (score 0):

If you can wait for Visual Studio 11 you can use attribute *[CallerFilePath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540%28VS.110%29.aspx)*.